# Usb sharing through Ethernet on Raspberry PI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, raspberry-pi2, ethernet

I'm looking at connecting 3 USB webcams to a Raspberry Pi 2 (or Orange Pi) and share them through Ethernet - eventually connecting them to my software NVR which is on the LAN.

[Here is the camera on Aliexpress (8mp USB Webcamera)](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/8MP-HD-3264X2448-Mjpeg-YuY2-170-degree-fisheye-lens-Sony-1-3-2-IMX179-mini-usb/32588980272.html)

I am considering usbip or virtualhere but don't know which one is best, virtualhere is not free and this project is just a experiment and not commercial

https://virtualhere.com

Is this even possible CPU wise, when sharing USB webcams does processing occur on the device? Is raspberry pi / orange pi powerful enough to share the devices? Does it matter how many devices I share or what I share?

I am also considering using the Orange pi One because I read it does not share the same bus as Ethernet eliminating one potential bottleneck.

Any comprehensive tips, gotchas, advice i need? much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The processing occurs on the pi to convert the USB signal to TCP and transmit it over the network. The pi3 is much more powerful than its predecessors so it can quite easily handle a webcam stream up to 1024x768 or more resolution.  Since the pi3 STILL shares its usb with the ethernet this greatly restricts the overall throughput with multiple webcams connected. But one or two at once should be ok. The pi has the best kernel and support, the pi clones like the odroid/banana/orange pi dont have as up-to-date kernels.

(Disclaimer: i wrote virtualhere)

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use [motioneyeOS](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki), in this link you can find:

- download and **installation** instructions
- list of supported devices including: Banana PI, Odroid C1/C1+, Odroid C2, Odroid XU4, Pine A64/A64+, Raspberry PI (A, B, A+, B+, Compute Module, Zero and Zero W models), Raspberry PI 2 and **Raspberry PI 3**

Including an [Usage Scenarios](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki/Usage-Scenarios) for you for multiple camera project.

https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki/Usage-Scenarios

Comment: If you continue with **Orange Pi** in mind, **motioneyeOS** is not working quite well but you can check: 

► [Kerberos.io](https://kerberos.io/) and mainly the [armbian instruccions](https://doc.kerberos.io/2.0/installation/Armbian).